Is it bad practice to pass block level constants as arguments into a function?
I'm wondering if it is bad practice or if it makes it harder to read if you define constants outside of a function and then pass them into the function as arguments?
const mainFunction = () => {
    const x = document.getElementById("example");
    y = subFunction1(x);
    z = subFunction2(x);
};

const subFunction1 = (x) => {
    // do something with x
};

const subFunction2 = (x) => {
    // do something else with x
};

I'm defining a constant in mainFunction and passing it into the sub functions. Would this make more sense just being a global constant? I'm in the early stages of learning javascript and I want to make sure I learn the best practices. thanks!
edit: I'm gathering that block level variables are a better practice than global. Would it then make it more readable to move the "const x" statement to each subfunction, or does this come down to personal preference at this point?

Just to be clear const refers to an immutable variable, not a true constant. So it is fine to use const in any context.

Don't make y and z implicit globals!

@NicholasTower if x will never change and the subfunctions will never be reused, is this still acceptable, or should I define x in each subfunction?

Explicitly passing values into functions is almost always more readable than having to look up where some implicitly inherited variable comes from.

I’m also not sure how exactly you’d define the same constant globally from within the function. Something would have to greatly change here in the process.

That is not "defining" x, that is "computing" x. Generally speaking (and everything true "generally speaking" might be false in specific cases. Computer science, nor any science, should be about learning a catalog of dogmas) computing something twice is a bad idea (here, "computation" is not heavy. it is just about querying the DOM. Yet, it is not a "definition", but a computation. It is not like in typed languages, where you have side-effect-less definition of variables). Besides, if it is the fact that isolated readers of subFunction might not be aware that x is immutable that

bothers you (but why? they can see that you don't modify it), then, they might also no be aware of t anything else about x, anyway. In untyped language, all they know is that the parameter is called x. If they want to know more, they need to read caller's code, or, better, comments.

It is perfectly fine.   Passing arguments to functions, no matter where they were instantiated, is 100% normal. I prefer my functions to take arguments v reading some external value/variable that I have much less control of.

It's totally ok to have the code you presented, except y and z should be declared somewhere.
But your code implies that subFunction1 and subFunction2 are generic and can act on other HTML elements (maybe restricted to the same type). If subFunction1 and subFunction2 are only valid for x or in mainFunction, better to define them inside mainFunction:
const mainFunction = () => {

    const x = document.getElementById("example");

    const subFunction1 = () => {
      // do something with x
    };

    const subFunction2 = () => {
      // do something else with x
    };

    const y = subFunction1();
    const z = subFunction2();
};


in my actual use case, my main reason for having these different functions is to organize the code and to test individual areas of my code. It seems in this case you are recommending to define the subfunctions within the main one. I am, however, worried about the main function getting too long

@RussellBoeger consider mainFunction as a scope rather than a small function. Then you can have any amount code in it, moreover if you pass x to mainFunction, you can apply it to different elements, that will give you multiple components with the same behaviour
